# How to make models of app available to other apps in a django project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-apps

It seems like to be best practice (or at least one common way) to create a Django 3 based fullstack project which uses project specific Django apps (instead of standalone Django apps) with a structure like this (refer to e.g. [here](https://www.toptal.com/django/django-top-10-mistakes)):

```
fullstack_project/
  frontend/
    ... # frontend stuff goes into here
  backend/  # Django project name
    apps/
      app1/
        apps.py
        logic.py
        models.py
        ...
      app2/
        apps.py
        logic.py
        models.py
      ...
    wsgi.py
    ...
  manage.py
```

The apps (here: `app1`) are integrated in the most basic form (no ruls, views, etc.) via `fullstack_project/backend/apps/app1/apps.py`

```
class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'backend.apps.app1'
```

and `fullstack_project/backend/settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'backend.apps.app1.apps.App1Config',
    'backend.apps.app2.apps.App2Config',
]
```

Using logic of one app (e.g. `app2/logic.py`) in another app (e.g. `app1/logic.py`) works just fine (e.g. via `from backend.apps.app2.logic import ...` in `app1/logic.py`).

However if I try to access the models of app1 in the logic of app2 I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`. I could implement a database wrapper for an app to allow cross-app database access. However ass the apps are cross-project anyway I'd like to avoid that and allow access more easily. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you add both apps in installed apps of settings

Comment: Yes. I improved the question.

Comment: are you doing any functionality in ```__init__.py``` of apps if so comment and check

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Right, I missed to remove debug code in the `__init__.py` of one of the apps. If you provide your comment as answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that there will be some code in `__init__.py` which is trying to access DB even before the app is registered and ready. so if you have any code in `__init__.py` comment it or make sure it will access database once the app is ready.

Comment: Removing code in __init__.py was the solution. However the code did not access the database (the app with code in it's __init__.py has no models at all).